# HBaseTestingUtility set Configuration Zookeeper clientPort not working

Tags: configuration, hbase, apache-zookeeper, hbasetestingutility

I use HBaseTestingUtility for my integration test. I want Zookeeper to listen on port 2181

```
HBaseTestingUtility testUtil = new HBaseTestingUtility();
testUtil.getConfiguration().set("hbase.zookeeper.property.clientPort", "2181");
MiniHBaseCluster cluster = testUtil.startMiniCluster();
```

However, Zookeeper keeps listen on a random port everytime the test runs.

```
LOG: Started MiniZK Cluster and connect 1 ZK server on client port: 62251
```

What's the problem here?

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
HBaseTestingUtility testUtil = new HBaseTestingUtility();
testUtil.getConfiguration().set("test.hbase.zookeeper.property.clientPort", "2181");
MiniHBaseCluster cluster = testUtil.startMiniCluster();
```

Comment: Not working in MacOS. Tried. Very strange because it works on another project in Windows.